# Preview transformation in vscode using javascript/typescript

Tags: node.js, json, visual-studio-code, transformation, dataweave

We are consuming apis returning json in our projects. The json from those api can contain rather large structures which need to be mapped into other large structures (usually json but could be xml or csv rarely).

We used to use dataweave (from Mulesoft) to do that, and if you're not familiar with dataweave, it's pretty good at that sort of mapping. It let's you define a sample input, and while editing the dataweave it shows you a preview of the result in a separate pane.

For some apis we switched to using nodejs (because it offers better control and debugging than Mule, long story). But I'd really like the same mapping experience as dataweave.

So I guess the question is: can I use vscode to define an input file in a directory, a transformation file in javascript and have the resulting mapped output display in a pane which is updated live?

Is there some plugin offering that? Couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the following:
You have a mule workflow which needs to read a file(you edited the file in vscode) and execute a server side javascript (nodejs) to transform the file and after the result is obtained, the mapped result will be pushed into a web page ?  right ?

All happen under a given mule workflow right? and you are wondering there is any mule connector to do this process ? right ?

Comment: No. What I'm asking is for a dataweave-like mapping experience in the javascript world.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugins that do quite what you're asking, but depending what tools you're using, you can just use built-in features for it.

VS Code let's you make a "split screen" with any two windows, or even more complex tile arrangements.  Here's what I might try in your situation:

(there are a ton of ways you could adjust or tweak this -- this is just one idea)

SETUP:

- Write your transformation script so that it takes file input (let's call this INFILE) and writes out to a file (let's call this OUTFILE).  These filenames could be hard-coded or passed into the transformation script.

SCREENS:

1. Left side, full height:  the script/transformation you're writing
2. Right side, top half: INFILE [i like to look at it for reference]
3. Right side, button half: OUTFILE [VS Code will auto-refresh any time this changes]

The last part of the puzzle is to run a command which will automatically rerun your script any time it changes. Since node 18, you can use `--watch` for this.  So run this in a script: `node --watch my-transform.js`

Now any time you save `my-transform.js`, it will rerun, putting new results in OUTFILE, which VS Code will refresh.